# How to get the basename when it gets truncated with period in path?

Tags: vbscript, path, basename

Am I missing a trick here?

```
Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

WScript.Echo fso.GetBaseName("D:\temp\1. Some Folder")
WScript.Echo fso.GetBaseName("D:\temp\Some Other Folder Without A Dot")
WScript.Echo fso.GetAbsolutePathName("D:\temp\1. Some Folder")
```

The code above for the basename gets truncated at the dot/period.

```
D:\temp\1
```

I'm assuming that VBScript is thrown by the dot. Is there a trick to getting around this? Or do you have to modify the full path after the last index of slash?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `GetFileName` will produce the result you're looking for.

From the docs:

> Returns the last component of a specified path that is not part of the drive specification.

Comment: That's good, but it doesn't explain why the basename gets truncated.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetBaseName` function indeed sees everything after the last dot as extension so the folder name you are expecting is truncated.

Safer, but **only for existing paths** could be to use the `GetFolder` function to receive a [Folder object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folder-object) and take the `Name` property from that:

```
WScript.Echo fso.GetFolder("D:\temp\1. Some Folder").Name
```

returns

> 1. Some Folder